# Populating infowindow in Google Map dynamically with html element (contentString variable)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using "get directions" functionality to create a simple route search script which finds the best route between two points.

When you get directions, it's in this form:

```
Turn left at...

Keep right...

Continue onto...
```

What I want is an option to click on these messages, which opens a marker on the map with info window. The problem is that the info window should contain the message clicked:

When I click "Keep right...", there should be a marker opened on the coordinate of that message with content "Keep right...". I'm missing the last part - populating a marker with such content.

Here are important parts of the code:

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService;
var map;
var contentString = ???;
var infoWindow;
var marker;
var Here;

function initialize() {
  var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true
  };
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  Here = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var myOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: Here,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel: true,
      scaleControl: true
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("guide"));
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

function calcRoute() {
  var request;
  var so;
  var start = document.getElementById("from").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("to").value;
...
  }
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
...
}
```

I tried populating contentString variable with some strings, even with "contentString", but nothing happens.

Here is a code of one of the rows with instructions:

```html
<tr jseval="setupPanelStep(this, $legIndex, $index)" jsselect="steps" jstcache="12" jsinstance="12">
  <td jscontent="($index + 1) + '.'" class="adp-substep" jstcache="14">13.</td>
  <td jsvalues=".innerHTML:format(instructions)" class="adp-substep" jstcache="15">Continue onto <b jstcache="0">A1</b><div style="font-size: 0.9em;" jstcache="0">Toll road</div></td>
  <td class="adp-substep" jstcache="0"><div jscontent="distance['text']" class="adp-distance" jstcache="16">123 km</div></td>
</tr>
```

This is part of the code which displays a script to the user:

```html
<form id="Googlemap" style="height:800px;" action="#">
<div style="width:250px; float:left;">
<div class="title">GET DIRECTIONS</div>
<div id="123">
<div style="width:250px; margin-bottom: 5px;"><span style="width:54px; float:left;">FROM</span>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
</div>
<div style="width:250px; margin-bottom: 5px;"><span style="width:54px; float:left;">TO</span>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
</div>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="tolls" /><label for="tolls">Avoid tolls</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="highways" /><label for="highways">Avoid highways</label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us abit more code that ties "turn left at.." with the info window?

Comment: @kjy112 There is no other code that connects driving instructions with the info window. I inserted question marks where some code should be inserted. However, I updated the question with more code (everything that could be important) and with the part of Google's driving instructions code.

Comment: @take2 where is your initial two points markers at?  you are missing the markers.  How do you get the direction without the initial two points?

Comment: @kjy112 I added more code, but I don't think it affects my original problem, since I probably have to pull value from this code that Google Maps return when you search for directions.

Comment: @take2 well, the problem is i do not where you are getting your two starting points and how you render the direction services from the start.

Comment: @kjy112 Here is the code on jsfiddle, but something is not working, I can't even get a map displayed. However, it's working on my localhost :/ http://jsfiddle.net/Vkbt9/

Comment: @take2 first of all you didn't call initialize onload.  secondly, you never created marker but yet you attached a click event to it.

Comment: @kjy112 I updated it with onload initialize, but still nothing changed - http://jsfiddle.net/Vkbt9/6/ I'm really confused about this marker part - there is only empty map loaded when someone opens a page. When you request directions, two markers will be displayed (from and to destinations).

Comment: @take2 try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/Vkbt9/5/ .  you never gave the map a center point and thus it won't show up.  when you request directions, you never created the markers for them.  in fact, you never created a marker at all, but yet attempt to attach click event to a null object

Comment: @kjy112 Ok, now I checked my whole code again and found that I accidentally deleted latlng coordinates (it was set to 0,0), sorry about that! However, I can't find anything related to markers, this is the whole code. Markers show up on from and to destinations and when you click on directions, info window shows up on the coordinate of clicked text (just as on maps.google.com when you use get directions option). In this version on jsfiddle, directions aren't visible at all.

Comment: @take2 i can help you build it part by part if you break it down because this question is just too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById(contentString)
});
```

where `contentString` is the HTML element ID